# Where does Puppet's environment come from?

Tags: linux, puppet

Self-training on `puppet` and wrote the following manifest:

```
class bratch::test {

  file { '/var/cache/tempFile':
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0644',
    source => "puppet://${puppetserver}/modules/bratch/tempFile"
  }

  exec { "create_file":
    command => "/bin/echo boop >> /tmp/outputFile",
  }
```

Works how I expected it but didn't really think about that exec line until after the fact.

If `puppet` understood the output redirection does that mean it invokes a shell? If so, where does it’s environment come from? Does it initialize the environment each time or does it inherit directly from the puppet agent?

Comment: Have you tried a command like `declare > /tmp/declarations` to see what the environment is?

Comment: Yeah I can find the environment after the fact, I was just trying to find out what influenced its creation.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec) is a bit confusing on this point:

> ### Providers
>
> #### posix
>
> Executes external binaries directly, without passing through a shell or performing any interpolation. This is a safer and more predictable way to execute most commands, but prevents the use of globbing and shell built-ins (including control logic like “for” and “if” statements).
>
> Default for `feature` == `posix`.
>
> #### shell
>
> Passes the provided command through `/bin/sh`; only available on POSIX systems. This allows the use of shell globbing and built-ins, and does not require that the path to a command be fully-qualified. Although this can be more convenient than the `posix` provider, it also means that you need to be more careful with escaping; as ever, with great power comes etc. etc.
>
> This provider closely resembles the behavior of the `exec` type in Puppet 0.25.x.

Therefore, if you use the `shell` provider, you should be able to use redirection, but the default is `posix`, which is direct execution, so unless you specified `shell`, which you didn't...

In either case, the documentation doesn't say much about the environment. One needs to examine [the code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/exec.rb#L30):

```
begin
  # Do our chdir
  Dir.chdir(dir) do
    environment = {}

    environment[:PATH] = resource[:path].join(File::PATH_SEPARATOR) if resource[:path]
```

Looks like it is set to empty and then populated with any settings we provide using the `environment` field, and so is reinitialized each time.

---

However, if we follow the breadcrumbs, we come to [the function call](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/exec.rb#L54) which does the execution:

```
      output = Puppet::Util::Execution.execute(command, :failonfail => false, :combine => true,
                              :uid => resource[:user], :gid => resource[:group],
                              :override_locale => false,
                              :custom_environment => environment)
```

`Execution.execute` calls [`execute_posix`](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/util/execution.rb#L184), which in turn [does](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/util/execution.rb#L271):

```
  command = [command].flatten
  ...
    options[:custom_environment] ||= {}
    Puppet::Util.withenv(options[:custom_environment]) do
      Kernel.exec(*command)
```

I don't know Ruby, I'd say that unless you specify a command and its arguments as an array explicitly, and only give a string like `"/bin/echo boop >> /tmp/outputFile"` , then the command line is passed as it is to [`Kernel.exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) , for which:

> the string is taken as a command line that is subject to shell expansion before being executed.

That is why you could use redirection without setting `shell` as the provider. Further, looking at [`withenv`](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/util.rb#L28), the `environment` array set above is simply used as a set of overrides. If the `environment` field is *not* specified, nothing is overridden. Hence the environment must be inherited from Puppet. Now what environment Puppet gets, I am not sure, but if run as a service on an Upstart-as-init system like Ubuntu, then at least [`TERM` and `PATH`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#job-environment) are available.

Comment: "but the default is `posix`, which is direct execution, so unless you specified shell, which you didn't" well according to the documentation: "Puppet will usually discover the appropriate provider for your platform" I didn't specify the provider so I'm guessing it did the autodetection and may have automatically selected `shell` because I had output redirection in the `exec` (just a wild guess, though).

Comment: @Bratchley `shell` is only available for POSIX platforms, and it says if `feature` is `posix`, the default is `posix`. Dunno what `feature` is, though. Note how it says the provider is detected based on the *platform*, not the *command*.

Comment: Looking at that code segment, though, it's still unclear to me how the environment is getting set. I saved [the output of `env`](https://dpaste.de/pSvh) to a file and it seems to have some variables that I don't think are coming from puppet itself though. For example, I don't see why it would set `TERM=xterm`

Comment: @Bratchley check the update.